# Categorise the list of data under a single value in ArrayList in Android.(See Description)

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, hashmap

Here is the for loop which prints all the contents of the array list:

```
        for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
        Log.e(TAG, "## Price \t\t"+arrayList.get(i).getPrice()+"\t\t\t"+arrayList.get(i).getDate());
    }
```

here is the output of log

`12-05 01:07:58.528 25822-25822/finlit.finlit E/ContentValues: ## Price         150         Added On:03/12/2017
12-05 01:07:58.528 25822-25822/finlit.finlit E/ContentValues: ## Price      75          Added On:03/12/2017
12-05 01:07:58.528 25822-25822/finlit.finlit E/ContentValues: ## Price      450         Added On:03/12/2017
12-05 01:07:58.528 25822-25822/finlit.finlit E/ContentValues: ## Price      356         Added On:04/12/2017
12-05 01:07:58.528 25822-25822/finlit.finlit E/ContentValues: ## Price      541         Added On:04/12/2017
12-05 01:07:58.528 25822-25822/finlit.finlit E/ContentValues: ## Price      415         Added On:04/12/2017
12-05 01:07:58.528 25822-25822/finlit.finlit E/ContentValues: ## Price      200         Added On:04/12/2017
12-05 01:07:58.528 25822-25822/finlit.finlit E/ContentValues: ## Price      600         Added On:04/12/2017
12-05 01:07:58.529 25822-25822/finlit.finlit E/ContentValues: ## Price      700         Added On:04/12/2017
12-05 01:07:58.529 25822-25822/finlit.finlit E/ContentValues: ## Price      70          Added On:04/12/2017
12-05 01:07:58.529 25822-25822/finlit.finlit E/ContentValues: ## Price      250         Added On:04/12/2017
12-05 01:07:58.529 25822-25822/finlit.finlit E/ContentValues: ## Price      250         Added On:04/12/2017
12-05 01:07:58.529 25822-25822/finlit.finlit E/ContentValues: ## Price      408         Added On:04/12/2017`

What is the possible way to add the sum of prices under a date. E.g A 
 hashmap {date , total sum of prices}.
To eloborate: On a given date : 03/12/2017 the total price is: 150+75+450=675.``
Hence categorise the further dates and their corresponding prices.
Hence for the hashmap **key**: 03/12/2017   **value**:675.
It would be appreciable if the code is available with date extracted using String functions and regex in java to extract required data.

Comment: If you have a large amount of this data, you're probably better off using a database and letting it do this work for you.  But for a small amount of data-  create a hashmap, and walk the list.  Add the total to the value already stored at that date in the hashmap.  If there is no data in the hashmap, use 0.  By the end of the list you'll have a hashmap of date->totals

Answer (score 0):

HashMap. Store Date as key.

```
      Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap();

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            if (map.containsKey(arrayList.get(i).getDate())) {
                map.put(arrayList.get(i).getDate(), arrayList.get(i).getPrice() + map.get(arrayList.get(i).getDate()));
            } else {
                map.put(arrayList.get(i).getDate(), arrayList.get(i).getPrice());
            }
        }

        // Iterate over Map
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "## Price \t\t"+entry.getValue()+"\t\t\t"+entry.getKey());
        }
```